# How to generalize a function to take more arguments? R

Tags: r, dplyr

Seems no one is able to tackle this, so I re-ask:

I would like to use an external function from sjstats package within my own function.

The external function takes 4 arguments as like: https://strengejacke.github.io/sjstats/reference/weighted_sd.html

```
weighted_mannwhitney(data, x, grp, weights, ...)
```

A simple call to that external function can be done like this.

```
weighted_mannwhitney(c12hour ~ c161sex + weight, efc)
```

I have built a simple function below, which currently only works when provided with data as input - **adding arguments produces errors.**

I would like to be able to pass on some arguments (data, x, grp, weights) to the internally called external functional, so I can change those arguments for different datasets.

**The Question**

My attempts at generalizing the function are not successful, can anyone show me how I can do this? I show how I would like to call the generalized function below.

```
library(sjstats) # has weighted Mann-Whitney function which I would like to automate within own function
library(tidyverse) 

data(efc)
efc$weight <- abs(rnorm(nrow(efc), 1, .3))

# Own working function 
own_funk <- function(data, ...) { 
  # Weighted MannWhitney Test p-value
  res <- data %>%
    summarise(
      across(
        c(c12hour,e17age), 
        ~sjstats:::weighted_mannwhitney.formula(.x ~ c161sex + weight, data)$p.value[[1]]
      )
    ) %>% 
    #round(., 3) %>% 
    tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%  
    pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from=rowname, values_from=value) %>%
    rename("Outcome" = 1, "P-value" = 2) %>%
    as.data.frame()
  
  return(res)
  
}
```

Call to own working function

`own_funk(efc)`

**How I would like to call the function**

```
# NB: The x can take on many variables  
own_funk(data = efc, x = c(c12hour,e17age), grp = c161sex, weights = weight)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat similar to @snaut's solution I'd use `map` to loop over your x columns/formulas. The difference mainly is that we probably don't want to hard code the variables within the function and rather pass these as an argument to the function.

```
library(sjstats) # has weighted Mann-Whitney function which I would like to automate within own function
library(tidyverse)
library(survey)

# Own working function 
own_funk <- function(data, x, grp, weights) { 
  # Weighted MannWhitney Test p-value
  
  formula <- paste0(x, " ~ ", grp, " + ", weights)
  
  res <- map2(.x = formula,
              .y = x,
              .f = ~ data |> 
                summarize(!!sym(.y) := sjstats:::weighted_mannwhitney.formula(as.formula(.x), data = data)$p.value[[1]]) %>% 
                #round(., 3) %>% 
                tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%  
                pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
                pivot_wider(names_from=rowname, values_from=value) %>%
                rename("Outcome" = 1, "P-value" = 2) %>%
                as.data.frame()) |> 
    bind_rows()
  
  return(res)
  
}

own_funk(data = efc, x = c("c12hour", "e17age"), grp = "c161sex", weights = "weight")
```

Which gives:

```
  Outcome     P-value
1 c12hour 0.006806572
2  e17age 0.187765467
```

Comment: Thanks!! Could you kindly elaborate what is happening within your code, especially within map2?

Comment: Sure, map2 "loops" over the .x and .y arguments. .x is the formula I build for each of your two variables, .y contains the two variables itself. And then in the first loop, the code in .f takes the first value of .x and the first value of .y and runs the code (i.e. creates a variable that contains the p-value from the current formula), then it does the same for the second values of .x and .y. And the last part with bind_rows glues that together into one data frame.

Comment: Adding the columns as arguments is definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

`sjstats:::weighted_mannwhitney.formula` is clearly meant for interactive use and not for programming. `sjstats:::weighted_mannwhitney.default` seems to be more suited for programming, but still does something with unqouting variable names that I did not quite figure out.

What I do most of the time when I have to use functions created to be used in an interactive way for programming is to create a temporary column with a fixed name and then rename the columns I want to iterate over to that column.

This is what I have done in my solution. I also don't use `summarise` and `across` but instead use `map_dfr` to iterate over the column names and output rows of a tibble.

I did not quite understand what you want to archive with the `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` but I'm sure you can format the output of my solution to your needs.

```
library(sjstats) # has weighted Mann-Whitney function which I would like to automate within own function
library(tidyverse) 

data(efc)
efc$weight <- abs(rnorm(nrow(efc), 1, .3))

# Own working function 
own_funk <- function(mydata, ...) { 
  # Weighted MannWhitney Test p-value
  
  map_dfr(
    c("c12hour", "e17age"),
    function(column){
      tmp_data <- mydata %>% 
        rename(tmp_col = {column})
      tibble(
        variable = column,
        `P-value`=sjstats:::weighted_mannwhitney.formula(tmp_col ~ c161sex + weight, data=tmp_data)$p.value[[1]]
      )
    }
    )
  
}

own_funk(efc)
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your solution as well! If I could accept both solutions I would definitely do that. Thank you very much as well!!